# Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [15,15], In[1]: [675,128]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm training a model on a custom dataset with about 4600 images of different shapes.

Here's a quick glimpse of the data:
[image]

[image]

It's a very simple model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# Arch
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation ='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here's the model's summary:

[image]

Then I tried the following:

```
trial = cv2.imread("Trial\\3.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(trial, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
plt.show()
gray = cv2.resize(gray, (15, 15))
#gray = img_to_array(gray)
#gray = np.expand_dims(gray, axis=0)

pred = model.predict(gray)
```

Which fails to predict and gives the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should this:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), input_shape=(15 * 15, ))
```

in first layer.